# spring cloud gateway trailing slash issue

Tags: spring-cloud

I am using spring-cloud-starter-gateway (Hoxton.SR5) 
When I try to call my application with slash it works.
http://localhost/myapp/

But when I call without slash 
http://localhost/myapp 
it is getting redirected to port on which myapp is running.

http://localhost:96/myapp/

Here's the yml

```
spring:
  application:
    name: gateway
  cloud:
    gateway:
      routes:
      - id: myapp
        uri: http://127.0.0.1:96
        predicates:
        - Path=/myapp, /myapp/**

server:
  port: 80
```

What am I doing wrong here. Any help be appreciated.

Comment: gateway doesn't redirect at all by default. can you confirm that the app running on port 96 is doing the redirect?

Comment: @spencergibb - i checked, app is not doing the redirect. The gateway works fine with trailing slash. Any thoughts?

Comment: @spencergibb - double checked. you're right, app is doing the redirect.

Answer (score 1):

I also faced the same issue but found that Path=/myapp/** should work in all cases be it /myapp or /myapp/4.
If you are getting 500 or 404 sometimes, please check if you are using a loadbalanced url (as in my case).

Comment: Redirect was due to trailing slash in tomcat
redirect-context-root: false

Comment: As mentioned above, add this property in your app redirect-context-root: false

Answer (score 1):

I was facing similar issue in an angular application with Spring. In my case for the page to load properly I need to add trailing slash to the URL. The below configuration redirects /myapp to /myapp/.

**Note:** It's observed that any mappings that start with /myapp MUST be present after this route.

Since Location header supports relative path as stated in [HTTP 1.1](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-7.1.2), this also made it easy to exclude hostname in `RedirectTo`.

```yaml
- id: myapp
  uri: no://op
  predicates:
  - Path=/myapp,false
  - Method=GET
  filters:
  - RedirectTo=302,myapp/
```